# Read in data from the user in a loop

Tags: common-lisp

For a little game I am working on, I want to read in the names of the players. I have two solutions so far which I find both a bit cumbersome. Version 1 forces the user to additionally state that he/she wants to add more players:

```
(defun read-player ()
  (loop :while (y-or-n-p "Add another player?")
        :do (format t "~& Name of player #~D: " (1+ (length players)))
        :collect (read-line) :into players
        :finally (print players)))
```

Version 2 needs a duplicate of the `format` expression:

```
(defun read-player2 ()
  (let ((players '()))
    (format t "~& Name of player #~D: " (1+ (length players)))
    (loop :for player = (read-line)
          :until (string= player "")
          :collect player :into players
          :do (format t "~& Name of player #~D: " (1+ (length players)))
          :finally (print players))))
```

Is there a synthesis of my two approaches? Not bothering the user with additional questions and not repeating code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about using `progn` when reading the player?

```
(defun read-players ()
  (loop :for player-count :upfrom 1
    :for player =
    (progn
      (format t "~& Name of player #~D (RET to stop): " player-count)
      (finish-output)
      (read-line))
    :while (plusp (length player))
    :collect player))
> (read-players)
 Name of player #1 (RET to stop): r
 Name of player #2 (RET to stop): g
 Name of player #3 (RET to stop): 
==> ("r" "g")
```

PS. It is relatively common to add a function like

```
(defun ask-user (format-string &rest format-arguments)
  (fresh-line)
  (apply #'format t format-string format-arguments)
  (finish-output)
  (read-line))
```

or, if you are fond of [`format`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/22_c.htm) magic,

```
(defun ask-user (format-string &rest format-arguments)
  (format t "~&~?: " format-string format-arguments)
  (finish-output)
  (read-line))
```

This would make your `read-players` even more readable:

```
(defun read-players ()
  (loop :for player-count :upfrom 1
    :for player = (ask-user "Name of player #~D (RET to stop)" player-count)
    :while (plusp (length player))
    :collect player))
```

Comment: Perfect! That's what I missed.

Comment: You should put a `FINISH-OUTPUT` before the `READ-LINE`. You could also use `"~?"` in `ASK-USER` instead of going through `APPLY`. That let's you put the freshline/colon/etc. there.

Comment: @jkiiski: Shouldn't additionally `*query-io*` be used as a stream when asking the user?